# how to hide tab when clicked on a select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#song">Song</a></li>
  <li id="image-tab"><a href="#image" data-toggle="tab">Image</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="image" class="tab-pane fade  ">
    <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="file" name="userfile" id="image">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="song" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="song-link" placeholder="Paste Soundcloud link here" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Music</option>
    <option value="2">Photography</option>
    <option value="3">Painting</option>
    <option value="4">Fashion</option>
    <option value="5">Modelling</option>
  </select>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have to hide image tab when I select music and song tab when I click the rest. I have tried to use display none using CSS but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly you mean by hide the tab? Does it mean that it will open the other tab? OR the tab will be totally unavailable to the end user for selection?

Comment: yeah the tab will be totally unavailable for selection. the content provided in tab and the title of the tab will be change based on the selection on select option  provided

Comment: please change the `id="image"` of `<input type="file"` as those are getting repeated for `div` as well as this `input` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at below approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-control").change(function() {
    setTabVisibility();
  });

  setTabVisibility();

  function setTabVisibility() {
    var selectedVal = $(".form-control").val();
    if (selectedVal == "1") {
      //Music selected 
      $("a[href='#image']").hide();
      $("div#image").hide().removeClass("in");;

      $("a[href='#song']").show()
      $("div#song").show().addClass("in");

      $('.nav-tabs a[href="#song"]').tab('show');

    } else {
      //other than Music selected 
      $("a[href='#song']").hide();
      $("div#song").hide().removeClass("in");

      $("a[href='#image']").show()
      $("div#image").show().addClass("in");

      $('.nav-tabs a[href="#image"]').tab('show');


    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#song">Song</a>
  </li>
  <li id="image-tab"><a href="#image" data-toggle="tab">Image</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="image" class="tab-pane fade  ">

    <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="file" name="userfile" id="imageupload">



  </div>


  <div id="song" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="song-link" placeholder="Paste Soundcloud link here" type="text">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Music</option>
    <option value="2">Photography</option>
    <option value="3">Painting</option>
    <option value="4">Fashion</option>
    <option value="5">Modelling</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

We need to `hide()` the `<a>` tag of Tab as well as need to `removeClass("in")` from corresponding tab content before showing the other tab.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to add and remove bootstrap classes `fade in` and `fade`.

for example if you want to hide the song tab and show the image tab, you will have to do the following:

First give your select an id

```
<select id="sel" class="form-control">
```

Then get the selected value like this:

```
<script>
     $('#sel').on('change', function() {
         alert(this.value);
     });
</script>
```

Finally, according to the selected value, hide and show your tabs:

```
<script>
     $('#sel').on('change', function() {
         if(this.value === 1){
              // hide image tab and show song tab
              $("#image").removeClass("fade in active");
              $("#image").addClass("fade");
              $("#song").removeClass("fade");
              $("#song").addClass("fade in active");
         } else {
              // hide song tab and show image tab
              $("#song").removeClass("fade in active");
              $("#song").addClass("fade");
              $("#image").removeClass("fade");
              $("#image").addClass("fade in active");
         }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: but what is the code for calling these code when u click on the options that are porvided. like showing song if 'music' is selected and image when any other is selected

Answer (score 0):

Give some id or class to `<select class="form-control" id="my-select">`

Give id or class to Song tab

```
<li class="active" id="song-tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#song">Song</a></li>
```

then check for change event.

```
    $("#my-select").on('change',function(){

    var strSelectedVal = $(this).val();

    $(".nav.nav-tabs li").show();

   if(strSelectedVal=="music"){

        $("#image-tab").hide();

    }else{

        $("#song-tab").hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: tab hides but the content inside the active tab doesnt appear. Also, i would want to show song tab as default and change to image later when the option is selected

Answer (score 0):

Add `ID` for your `select`:

```
<select id="select" class="form-control">
  Options
</select>
```

Then you have to check the value of the selected option and hide the image tab when it is `music` by showing another tab (I expect that you want to change to song tab).

```
$('#select').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() === '1') {
    $('#song-tab').tab('show');
  }
});
```

I also made some minor changes in your HTML.

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/EyWYdG)**